# XSLT 2.0 preserve space after element

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0, saxon

I have a xml file like this:

```
<p>Consideriamo una retta che passa per i punti <em>P</em><sub>1</sub> di coordinate (<em>x</em><sub>1</sub>; <em>y</em><sub>1</sub>). </p><ul><li>text...</li><li>Other...</li></ul>
```

I need to transform (with xslt Saxon PE) indent in only block elements, not the inline elements, something like:

```
<p>Consideriamo una retta che passa per i punti <em>P</em><sub>1</sub> di coordinate (<em>x</em><sub>1</sub>; <em>y</em><sub>1</sub>). </p>
<ul>
  <li>text...</li>
  <li>Other...</li>
<ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run with schema validation on the result document (which would need Saxon-EE), then `indent="yes"` will not do any indentation in mixed content elements, which is the effect you are looking for.

Alternatively, consider the extension `xsl:output/@saxon:suppress-indentation` ([which has moved into the standard in 3.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#serialization)). This allows you to list element names (such as p) whose content will not be indented.

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
<xsl:output  indent="yes"/>
```

Comment: To have the XSLT serializer recognize (X)HTML block elements that needs to be `<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>` (respectively `<xsl:output method="xhtml" indent="yes"/>`), I think. http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-xquery-serialization/#HTML_INDENT.